# Creating Image Mosaic database table in GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, postgis-2.0

When I create an image mosaic store in geoserver, the table is automatically created in the PostGIS database.

If it is possible to alter the table name, how will GeoServer know what table to look to?

Comment: I don't think so, why would you want to?

Comment: In my case, I have derived parameters for thickness, such as 1000-500mb thickness, 1000-850mb thickness, etc. However, when geoserver reads the grib file, the grib name is Thickness_isobaric_layer. Therefore, when 1000-500mb thickness is created, 1000-850mb cannot be created because they have duplicate table names. In addition, if one derived parameter is from the NAM model, and one is from the GFS model, they would still have duplicate Thickness_isobaric_layer table names which is not allowed. Any way to make the table names unique would be helpful

Comment: I found out that if you change the indexer.xml and coverages.xml, you can change <name>new_name</name> if you make sure you have <origName>original_name</origName>. Also make sure that your schema attributes are correct. In my case, I kept getting an error that attribute "isobaric_layer" was null, but i included it in the schema attributes as "isobaric_layer:Double" and everything worked.

Comment: you should add (and later accept) this as an answer for future users

Answer (score 2):

I found out that if you change the indexer.xml and coverages.xml, you can change `<name>new_name</name>` if you make sure you have `<origName>original_name</origName>`. Also make sure that your schema attributes are correct. In my case, I kept getting an error that attribute "isobaric_layer" was null, but i included it in the schema attributes as "isobaric_layer:Double" and everything worked.